# C# Get Child Rows Column Issue

Tags: c#, database

I am working on a database program in c# and want to add the data relations to the project. I am having issues with the getting of the child rows, however. I have used the code provided by Microsoft's documentation:

```
    static void childRows() {
        DataRow[] arrRows;

        foreach(DataRelation relation in dataSet.Tables["Artist"].ChildRelations) {
            foreach(DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["Artist"].Rows) {
                arrRows = row.GetChildRows(relation);

                for(int i = 0; i < arrRows.Length; i++) {
                    foreach(DataColumn column in dataSet.Tables["Artist"].Columns) {
                        Console.WriteLine(arrRows[i][column.ColumnName]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

But I am getting an error saying that the second column (the name of the artist) does not exist in the linked table; which I would think wouldn't be a problem.

My data relations are:

```
r1 = new DataRelation("Artist_Records", dataSet.Tables["Artist"].Columns[0], dataSet.Tables["Record"].Columns[1]);
r2 = new DataRelation("Label_Records", dataSet.Tables["RecordLabel"].Columns[0], dataSet.Tables["Record"].Columns[4]);

dataSet.Relations.Add(r1);
dataSet.Relations.Add(r2);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to add the relation on the dataset, as mentioned in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did, I'll add that to the question

Comment: I think this should help - http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/dataset/Lesson06.htm

Comment: Or may be this as well - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c59e94/defining-datarelation-in-a-dataset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            foreach(DataRelation relation in dataSet.Tables["Artist"].ChildRelations) 
            {
                   foreach(DataRow row in  relation.ChildTable.AsEnumerable())
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString())));
                   }
                   DataTable dt2 = relation.ChildTable.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
            }
```

Comment: That works! Is there a way to get the code to work for creating a new datatable using the information from the other tables or should I use something else?